# CSS Animation for SVG not working

Tags: css, svg

I understand this animation should work on SVGs as it does on HTML elements but obviously I am wrong!

How do I achieve this effect with CSS on an SVG? [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/strdyy77/1/).

```
div {
  background: blue;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    filter: brightness(1);
    filter: contrast(1);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1);
    -webkit-filter: contrast(1);
  }
  50% {
    filter: brightness(0.1);
    filter: contrast(0.1);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(0.1);
    -webkit-filter: contrast(0.1);
  }
  100% {
    filter: brightness(1);
    filter: contrast(1);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1);
    -webkit-filter: contrast(1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the `div` from css to `svg` . It works for me.

Or if you want to see both the `div and svg`, just add `div, svg { css code..}`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4ebv7jzd/1/

Comment: Hi @Ovidiu Unguru I asked a slightly different version of my screw up question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073426/css-animation-on-svg-group

Comment: Remember that this will not work in IE or Edge ... need js fallback